# Any distribution function can be expressed as a sum of absolutely continuous, singular, and discrete distribution functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am trying to show that any distribution function (increasing, right continuous, $F(-\infty) = 0$, $F(\infty) = 1$) can be uniquely expressed as a sum of an absolutely continuous d.f., a singular continuous d.f., and a discrete d.f.

Let $F'$ be the derivative of $F$ where it exists an let the AC part be
$$g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x F'(t)dt.$$
We have $g'(x) = F'(x)$ almost everywhere and thus the singular part is 
$$h(x) = F(x)-g(x)$$
so that $h'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

Where is the discrete part, and how do we show this is a unique decomposition? How can one prove this without using extensive measure theory?

Comment: See Theorem 1.3.2 of Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory'.

Comment: The proof is left as an exercise in Chung's book.